# matching files using curly brace expansion in zsh

Tags: zsh, wildcards, brace-expansion

In `bash` I can use curly braces to pattern match several files, e.g.

```
ls *.{dot,svg,err}
```

If there's no file for a particular extension, I get a warning, but the remaining files will be listed.

> ls: cannot access '*.err': No such file or directory

**However**, in `zsh` I get an error instead and **no output** is produced for the existing files.

> zsh: no matches found: *.err

This is also applies for removing, where attempting to remove files with this:

```
rm -f *.{dot,svg,err}
```

Will remove all matching files in `bash` without any error or warning,
but in `zsh` it will err out and not remove anything at all.

**Is there a way to make `zsh` behave in the same way as `bash`, or is there another way to remove/list the existing files with similar ease¹?**

---

¹Obviously I can do something like `find . -name '*.dot' -or -name '*.svg' -or -name '.err' | xargs rm` but that's not particularly easy/practical.

Comment: do `setopt BRACE_CCL` first then give it one more try

Comment: @Rahul setting it didn't affect it in any way.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You don't get a *warning in `bash`*, you get an *error* by `ls` (you'll find that `ls` exit status is non-0 which indicates it has failed).

In both `zsh` and `bash`, `{...}` is not a globbing operator, it's an expansion that occurs before globbing.

In:

```
ls -d -- *.{dot,svg,err}
```

(you forgot the `-d` and `--` btw), the shell expands the `{...}` first:

```
ls -d -- *.dot *.svg *.err
```

and then does the glob. `bash` like most Bourne-like shells has that misfeature that non-matching globs are passed as-is. While on `zsh`, a non-matching glob is an error.

See how `rm -f [ab].c` in `bash` could delete the `[ab].c` file if there was no file called `a.c` nor `b.c`. In `zsh`, you'd get a *no match* error instead. See the `failglob` option in `bash` to get a similar behaviour.

```
ls -d -- *.{dot,svg,err}(N)
```

in `zsh` would enable the `nullglob` option on all 3 globs, so that if the globs don't match, they are removed, but that's probably not what you want, because if none of the globs match any file, the command will become:

```
ls -d --
```

Which will list `.` (the current directory) instead.

Best here is to use **one** glob that matches files with either of the 3 extensions:

```
ls -d -- *.(dot|svg|err)
```

That will give a sorted list of files to `ls`, `ls` will be run unless there's no file found matching that one pattern.

You also have the option to enable the `sh`/`bash` (bogus IMO) behaviour with `emulate sh` or with `unsetopt nomatch`. A slightly better approach is to enable the `csh` behaviour (which was also the behaviour of Unix shells before the Bourne shell was released):

```
setopt cshnullglob
```

With that option, the command is cancelled only if **all** the globs on the command line fail to match. If at least one matches, all the ones that don't match are removed so:

```
ls -d -- *.{dot,svg,err}
```

Will expand the `dot`, `svg` and `err` in turn, omitting the missing ones.

If you want to compare the effect on the order of the arguments of the different approaches, you need a command that (contrary to `ls`) doesn't sort them before displaying. With GNU `ls`, you can pass the `-U` option for that, or since `ls` does only print its arguments here, just use `printf '%s\n' *...` instead.

Answer (score 4):

Tack on `(N)` to the pattern; this tells zsh to not be upset about missing matching.

```
rm -f *.{dot,svg,err}(N)
```

It's a `zsh` glob feature. See `man zshexpn` for more details; under "Glob Qualifiers". It's annotated as "sets the NULL_GLOB option for the current pattern".